# javascript concatenated file has slower runtime than the separate files

Tags: javascript, concatenation, createjs

I am working on a big javascript project and I encountered something I didn't expect to happen. In my index.html I load dozens of javascript files and the framerate (it's based on createjs) is around 30. After my build script is run, all these javascript files have been concatenated into one and minified. However, the framerate has dropped to 10 in Safari on the iPad 3 (similar behaviour on iPad 4). I tried without minifying and only did the concatenation, but then still only a fps of 10. Another test I did was manually splitting my all.js into 3 separate files and this increased the fps to 15.

What's happening here? I though that concatenating would result in a lower loading time and less http requests, but wouldn't result in a slower runtime. Was this to be expected? Can I do something else or should I stop concatenating into 1 file?

Comment: What magnitude are the sizes of these files of? 10Kb, 100Kb, 1Mb?

Comment: The minified javascript file is a little less than 4MB.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that maybe Safari does not handle well very large files. It is possible that it first reads the whole file to memory and then processes it. But if it begins from a small buffer that needs to be enlarged every time, then is when memory allocation delays appear.

What to do in this case? Appart than returning to shorter files distribution (which turn to be more reusable), I still think of another chance:

What about **compressing** the 4Mb file? If you could program the server endpoint to serve it compressed (in gzip, for example), that surely would reduce its size to a 10%-20% (since text files are easily compressed to a high ratio).

(Ahem... I have to admit I would have expected a better performance with a single, large file - like you did. But before tested, one can never tell...)